# Confused about the proper order of try and with in Python

Tags: python, try-catch, with-statement, contextmanager

I read here that it is recommended to use `with open(filename)` instead of using the pair `open(filename)` and `filename.close()` (at least for basic tasks) and that it is also better to use `try`.

Q1: If my understanding is correct, what would be the proper order ?

```
try:
  with open(filename) as f:
    do something, eg. match string
```

or

```
with open(filename) as f:
  try:
    do something, eg. match string
```

Q2: Which case is better if I want also to insert some code to bring up a popup for file handling error ? (for file not found, or something)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Keep your `try` / `except` statement as close to the source of the exception as possible.

If you are not catching `IOError`s, put it inside the `with` statement. On the other hand, if it is an exception that `open()` throws, put it *around* the `with` statement.

If the `with` statement is longer or you don't want to mask the same exception being raised in the `with` statement suite, execute the `open()` call *first*:

```
try:
    fileobj = open(filename)
except IOError:
    print('File problems!')
else:
    with fileobj as f:
        # do something
```